# How to get Contours in ncWMS thredds vertical section for getVerticalSection request

Tags: gis, netcdf, thredds

How to get Contours in ncWMS thredds vertical section for getVerticalSection request. I need to obtain some pngs with contours on them for a project using thredds 5.0.0,  I am unable to find find any API parameter for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The THREDDS Data Server (TDS) v5.x uses the `edal-java` 2.x stack, so it's a little different than `ncwms1.2`. I think what you want in the new version is a `GetTransect` request, perhaps something like:

`REQUEST=GetTransect&LAYERS=<layer>&CRS=<crs>&LINESTRING=<lat/lon pairs>&FORMAT=<format>&TIME=<iso time string>&COLORSCALERANGE=<range>&NUMCOLORBANDS=<num_bands>&PALETTE=<palette>`

The `GetTransect` request is described in the `GetCapabilities` document returned by the ncwms2 service in the TDS. [Here](http://godiva.rdg.ac.uk/ncWMS2/wms?REQUEST=GetTransect&LAYERS=foam/TMP&CRS=CRS:84&LINESTRING=-173.60273633007%202.9347768402519,%20-100.23053418164%202.9347768402519&FORMAT=image/png&TIME=2011-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&COLORSCALERANGE=269,306&NUMCOLORBANDS=250&PALETTE=psu-inferno) is an example using the University of Readings ncwms2 server:

Note that the new ncwms2 server in TDS v5 is experimental, and not everything between the TDS and ncwms2 is hooked up, so your request may not work. Also, TDS v5 is just now in its first beta release, so bugs unrelated to the new ncwms server may pop up.